# I am trying to do hierachial clustering on my data set in which I want to cluster the debtor names into 3 categories

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to group my data into 3 clusters based on past behaviour of debtor in R

I am using dtwclust package to do hiearchial clustering using DTW distance. My data set has 4000 rows- years are in columns. I want to  cluster into 3 groups. It is taking forever to run. Is there any better method to do or I am doing something wrong?

```
install.packages("BBmisc")
install.packages("dtwclust")
cluster_data <- data.frame(name = LETTERS, x2001 = 1:26 , x2002 = 27:52,x2003 = 52:77)
remit.norm <- BBmisc::normalize(cluster_data, method="standardize")
remit.norm <- remit.norm[-1,-1]
cluster_dtw_h <- tsclust(remit.norm, type = "h", k = 3L,  distance = "dtw", control = hierarchical_control(method = "complete"), seed = 390, preproc = NULL)
```

Comment: If you are using this for real application, recommend rethinking applying STS. See here [https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/meaningless.pdf] & here [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4130317/#!po=12.2642]

Comment: Hi , could you suggest me a better approach to solve my problem

Comment: Sure! What is the overall classification goal? Three distinct groups based on what variables?

Comment: Hi, so I have ids in the first column and rest of the columns are years.So I want to cluster these ids which basically are the debtors based on their past behaviour -i.e the number of pending invoices over these years. Each row represents the number of prending invoices of a debtor over the years.Have to classify them into groups- High Risk,Medium Risk,Low Risk

Answer (score 0):

I dont't understand because for me the code above works almost instantaneously. You can also try the `TSdist` package with `hclust` function you may succed better. Hope it will help

Comment: Hi, the code works fine for smaller datasets.I have used 500 rows still takes a minute or two to run.But as I increase the dataset to 4000 rows the code is running forever.Thanks will use your suggestion.

Comment: I don't know if it will better work, if yes I will be happy to have some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.
DTW is expensive, and if you have 4k series,
hierarchical clustering needs to perform 8 *million* DTW calculations,
and that's gonna take time.
Nevertheless, you're using the `dtw::dtw` distance,
which is **not** optimized for cross-distance matrices.
Try using `distance = "dtw_basic"`,
which is the multi-threaded version included in `dtwclust`,
and see `help("dtw_basic")`
(consider using a window constraint).
Also check the [timing experiments](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/vignettes/timing-experiments.html#dtw-1) to get an idea of the running times you should expect,
which will probably in the order of minutes to hours.

Comment: Hi, I used kml package which is designed for clustering longitudinal data and it worked almost instantaneously.So is it a preferred method for time series clustering ?

Comment: I'd say that's for you to decide.